# Can we use a create procedure in pre copy script azure - azure data factory

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am trying to use a create or alter Procedure in pre copy script of azure copy activity. My intention is not to copy data but to create for alter my stored procedure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need not to copy the data then Use Lookup activity in Azure Data Factory.

- Need to use **Lookup** activity to execute any Ad-hoc SQL script in Azure data factory.
- Inside lookup activity select a dataset which is pointing to your database
- Select query option and type your script in Query field.

[image]

Please refer for more info: [Lookup activity in Azure Data Factory - Azure Data Factory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity)

Comment: Hi ,I tried using lookp up activity but its expects a return value .For example
create or alter proecure ABC
as
begin
select * from testtable;
end
--go return 0 
--Also added return 0 to as it expect a return value

Comment: I agree the storedprocedure not able to run on Query tab. Something missing on Execute Storedprocedure SQL task  in Lookup Activity. The main constraint of lookup activity is needs some sort of output result set. I have alternate solution You can add your Stored procedure in your SQL Server. After you can choose lookup activity -> Settings -> switch query to Storedprocedure.